# SQL Server differential backup failure

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-backups

I have noticed a failure of a differential backup in our maintenance plan. It appears to be the result of an attempted enterprise vault copy but cannot confirm this at the present time. The previous full backup was done at 5:00pm and the failure occurred at 11:30pm.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9nux.jpg)

The log file is here:

```
Microsoft(R) Server Maintenance Utility (Unicode) Version 10.50.6220
Report was generated on "server_name".
Maintenance Plan: db_name backup Differential
Duration: 00:00:00
Status: Warning: One or more tasks failed.
Details:
Back Up Database Task (server_name)
Backup Database on Local server connection
Databases: DB_NAME
Type: Differential
Append existing
Task start: 2017-07-12T23:30:01.
Task end: 2017-07-12T23:30:02.
Failed:(-1073548784) Executing the query "BACKUP DATABASE [DB_NAME] TO  DISK = N'C:..." failed with the following error: "Cannot perform a differential backup for database "DB_NAME", because a current database backup does not exist. Perform a full database backup by reissuing BACKUP DATABASE, omitting the WITH DIFFERENTIAL option.
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Command:EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N''C:\Full Backups\Differentials\DB_NAME''

GO
BACKUP DATABASE [DB_NAME] TO  DISK = N''C:\Full Backups\Differentials\DB_NAME\DB_NAME_backup_2017_07_12_233001_9226889.bak'' WITH  DIFFERENTIAL , NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N''DB_NAME_backup_2017_07_12_233001_9070642'', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10
GO
declare @backupSetId as int
select @backupSetId = position from msdb..backupset where database_name=N''DB_NAME'' and backup_set_id=(select max(backup_set_id) from msdb..backupset where database_name=N''DB_NAME'' )
if @backupSetId is null begin raiserror(N''Verify failed. Backup information for database ''''DB_NAME'''' not found.'', 16, 1) end
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM  DISK = N''C:\Full Backups\Differentials\DB_NAME\DB_NAME_backup_2017_07_12_233001_9226889.bak'' WITH  FILE = @backupSetId,  NOUNLOAD,  NOREWIND

GO
```

Problem is that I can't seem to find this new full backup that has been created that the differential backup from 12:30am have as their base? Is there a way to find what base file a differential points to?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: Apologies @marc_s .It seems I can't do that with my reputation so happy to have it moved if you can help

Answer (score 0):

One way is to automate this job through PowerShell scripts (easily available on various forums), where you will be able to set separate parameters for incremental, full and differential backups.
Another way I prefer is to do this task using a dedicated backup software setup.
Earlier I had MS DPM to manage SQL backups, and it really worked awesomely.
I have also tried Cloudberry backup for SQL servers and it is also a light and reliable cloud based backup tool.